# JavaScript: parenthesis surrounding comma separated values

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to get my head around the reason JS picks the last element (`8`):

```
var values = (null, 7, null, 8);
console.log(values); 
// Output: 8
```

`console.log` and `alert` behaves the same so I assume it's something to do with the language itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the first line of [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and **returns the value of the last operand**.

Answer (score 0):

This one also explained beautifully [link](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)

The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand

Comment: Not "both of", but "all of", and not "second", but "last".